# python построение графика линейной функции

Tags: python, математика, graph

Есть точки графика в массиве [[x,y],[x,y]] и тд, как по первым двум точкам построить прямую и найти где далее график лежит на этой прямой.
Была идея построить прямую и все значения через которые она проходит сохранять в другой массив, далее другим циклом сверять значения, но это очень ресурсозатратно т.к. график на 40мб файла.
Можно ли это делать налету? p.s. Визуальное отображение не нужно.
С примера картинки: по 1,1 и 2,2 строим прямую и налету находим что 7,7 и 12,12 лежат на ней.

[image: graph]

Comment: Если "визуальное отображение" не нужно, то ваш вопрос бессмысленно. Переформулируйте его так, чтобы было однозначно понятно, что вам требуется сделать.

Comment: Ну так первые два считали, нашли уравнение, все, пошли дальше — считываем каждую точку, проверяем, что она удовлетворяет уравнению или нет. В вашем примере находит по первым двум точкам `y=x`, и идя по точкам, проверяем выполнение этого условия для каждой. Только вот сама постановка задачи кажется странной... Что за хитрые данные такие, что именно первые две точки все точно определяют?...

Answer (score 3):

Ищем коэффициент: разница между первыми двумя точками по `y`, делённая на разницу по `x`. А потом для каждой следующей точки проверяем, что у неё такой же коэффициент разности координат с первой точкой выходит. Только поскольку числа с плавающей точкой не совсем точные, проверяем коэффициент не на точное совпадение, а с некоей погрешностью:

```
def calc_coeff(points, i, j):
    return (points[j][1]-points[i][1])/(points[j][0]-points[i][0])

points = [[1,1],[2,2],[4,3],[5,7],[7,7],[10,8],[10,12],[12,12],[14,13]]
bias = calc_coeff(points, 0, 1)
epsilon = 1e-5
for i in range(2, len(points)):
    if abs(calc_coeff(points, i, 0) - bias) < epsilon:
        print(points[i])
```

Вывод:

```
[7, 7]
[12, 12]
```

Переделать этот код под потоковый режим поступления данных совсем не сложно, тут весь доступ к данным последовательный. Единственное что - нужно будет запомнить куда-то координаты первой точки и передавать их в функцию подсчёта коэффициента.

Comment: Немного дополню. Представленное решение справедливо, если  прямая проходит через точку (0,0). Что на рисунке представлено, но из условия никак не вытекает. Это приводит к тому, что в уравнении появляется второй коэффициент. (в регрессии он называется коэффициентом смещения). Найти его не трудно, он равен представленному в ответе коэффициенту умноженному на x1 минус y1. В частном случае (как на картинке, но только в этом случае) этот коэффициент становится равным 0.

Comment: @passant Посмотрите получше решение, оно работает в общем случае.

Comment: @passant Я не использую точку (0,0), у меня в качестве отправной точки используется первая точка в последовательности данных :)

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, помогло!